# MDX date filter not working properly

Tags: date, ssas, mdx

I am facing this weird behavior for below MDX...where when service date is less than 20170630 I get data for all available service dates till 20171030 but when I reduce the date range I get nothing even though those records were shown earlier with the larger range. Could anyone please help what could be the cause of such behavior.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[date_dateid__servicedate] as [Service Date].[Date ID].currentMember.name

MEMBER [Measures].[vendor_vendorname] as [Vendor].[Vendor Name].currentMember.name

MEMBER [Measures].[corporation_corpcode] as [Corporation].[Corp Code].currentMember.name

MEMBER [Measures].[billingcategory_billcategory] as [BillingCategory].[Bill Category].currentMember.name

MEMBER [Measures].[afe_afenumber] as [Afe].[Afe Number].currentMember.name

MEMBER [Measures].[afeproperty_wellname] as [Afe Property].[Well Name].currentMember.name

MEMBER [Measures].[dailygrossexpenses_grossactual] as [Measures].[Gross Actual]

MEMBER [Measures].[dailygrossexpenses_grossexpenseandotherincome_expenseamount] as [Measures].[Gross Expense and Other Income - Expense Amount]

 SELECT 
 { [Measures].[date_dateid__servicedate],
   [Measures].[vendor_vendorname],
   [Measures].[corporation_corpcode],
   [Measures].[billingcategory_billcategory],
   [Measures].[afe_afenumber],
   [Measures].[afeproperty_wellname],
   [Measures].[dailygrossexpenses_grossactual],
   [Measures].[dailygrossexpenses_grossexpenseandotherincome_expenseamount] 
  } ON columns , 
SUBSET(ORDER(NONEMPTY({ [Vendor].[Vendor Name].Children
       *[Service Date].[Date ID].Children
       *[Corporation].[Corp Code].Children
       *[BillingCategory].[Bill Category].Children
       *[Afe].[Afe Number].Children
       *[Afe Property].[Well Name].Children }, 
{[Measures].[Gross Actual],
 [Measures].[Gross Expense and Other Income - Expense Amount]}), 
 [Measures].[vendor_vendorname],                   
BASC), 0 ,50 )ON rows 
FROM (SELECT { [Vendor].[Vendor Name].&[160] } on columns 
  FROM ( SELECT [Service Date].[Date ID].&[20170831]:[Service Date].[Date ID].&[20170930] on columns 
    FROM [XXXX] ))
```

Comment: can you make the script as small as possible but still with the same behaviour

Comment: I was able to get it working by correcting the relationships in dimension usage.It was on date with service dimension when changed to dateid it started working fine.